# Running development.ini after changes

Tags: python, pyramid

I have made changes in development.ini. How do I run it again, so the changes are seen?
when I run

```
 ../bin/pserve development.ini
```

I get an error that the adsress is already taken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three options:

- You have another terminal open with `pserve` still running. Find it and stop pserve there.
- You are still running `pserve` in daemon (background) mode. Check with `pserve development.ini status`. If a daemon is running, stop it with `pserve development.ini stop`, or if you *want* it to run in background modus, use `pserve development.ini restart`.
- You changed the port to something that conflicts with an already running program. You'll have to figure out what that is. Try connecting to that port with your browser or using the `telnet` command, for example. Either change your `development.ini` to not conflict or stop the other program.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the --reload argument on start up. That way any file changes you make will restart the pserver daemon.